# User group membership appears to be empty

Tags: 18.04, permissions, user-management, groups

I appear to be having issues with group membership for the single user on my Ubuntu laptop. I found this initially when trying to access a USB stick and finding I was getting access denied. I checked I was a member of the group the device was being assigned when mounting but I can only access with sudo or by changing the permissions to o+rw

I've just installed docker and again I can only run under sudo as running as an unprivileged account gives an access denied error to the docker.sock file. Weirdly when I query my groups I get none but when I query for the user I am logged on as I get them. It appears as though there is some problem with assigning groups to the logged in account. This has been happening for several weeks and I've logged off/rebooted many times.

*lsb-release*

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
```

*File permissions*

```
$ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock 
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Oct 22 09:14 /var/run/docker.sock
```

*User*

```
$ whoami
rob
```

*Groups*

```
$ groups
rob
```

**but**

```
$ groups rob
rob : rob adm disk dialout cdrom sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev fuse lpadmin scanner sambashare vboxusers docker
```

Is there something corrupted here?